# XAML designer with UserControls in DLL doesn't resolve resource

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2019, made of some projects built as DLL using WPF .NET 5.

Now I need to create some `UserControls` inside one of this projects, that I will load in a future WPF .NET 5 application, but the problem is that the XAML designer is not able to preview the `UserControl` with `StaticResource` that are in an external `ResourceDictionary`.

I simplify the code:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="sButton" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource color_UC_BorderBrush}"/>
            </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Having only DLL I don't have an `Application` with shared `ResourceDictionary` and `color_UC_BorderBrush` could not be resolved for preview.

In the following way instead the XAML designer works properly, but I don't want that every single `UserControl` loads his own `ResourceDictionary` everytime:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyLib;component/ResourceDictionaries/myRD.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Style x:Key="sButton" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource color_UC_BorderBrush}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

In my future WPF .NET 5 application I will use shared `ResourceDictionary` but for now **how can I manage to let the XAML designer works properly inside a DLL or how can I make the `MergedDictionary` defined in the XAML ignorable?**

Maybe there are other ways I don't have in mind. Thank you.

Comment: I don't have a solution to your specific use case. Because it seems like a non-issue to me. Shouldn't the `UserControl` library come with its own default visual properties? It seems well and good to provide a mechanism for client code to override those properties, but why force them to? Providing default values for everything would simplify both your life (since the above issue goes away) as well as that of the author of the client code (since they only have to provide visual properties when they care about them).

Comment: @PeterDuniho What do you mean as "default values"? Now I'm considering `StaticResource color_UC_BorderBrush` as the default value, so if I want to change the value of multiple properties of multiple controls I can simple edit the resource value, is it wrong?

Comment: I mean that your design appears to require the _client_ to provide values for the brush, even if the client code doesn't care what color is used. Contrast this to every other UI element published by a library other than your own code, in which if some color is needed, there is a default color that is provided without additional effort on your part. Does `TextBlock` require you to provide a foreground brush? Does `Button` require you to provide brushes for the background, border, focus highlight, etc? No, they don't. You can supersede them if you want, but you don't _have_ to.

Answer (score 0):

You can't omit merging the resource into a `ResourceDictionary` within the scope of the control that depends on it.

But instead of merging the same resource into each control's `ResourceDictionary`, you can choose a `ResourceDictionary` of a common parent. The XAML resource lookup strategy will traverse the logical tree to search for the required resource, starting at the local `ResourceDictionary` of the control and ending at the root, before checking *App.xaml* and *Generic.xaml*.

In case of the `UserControl`, you would have to use the `DynamicResource` markup extension. This is, because the content will only be part of of the logical tree during runtime. In design time, the root from the user control's content point of view is the containing `UserControl`.

You should know that `DynamicResource` has a performance penalty. So you typically would try to avoid it.
Also defining the resource in each control's `ResourceDictionary` will introduce a performance penalty.
The best solution is to define the resource in the application's root control like `Window.Resources` or even better in the `ResourceDictionary` inside *App.xaml*.
Using *App.xaml* to host the merged `ResourceDictionary` would also allow to use the cheaper `StaticResource` from inside the `UserControl` to lookup the merged resources.

Please read [Static and dynamic resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/fundamentals/xaml-resources-define?view=netdesktop-5.0#static-and-dynamic-resources) to learn more about the lookup behavior of the XAML engine.

The following example chooses the `MainWindow` as the host for the merged resources. It is the root of all it's contained elements and therefore reachable from any location in its logical tree.

**MainWindow.xaml**
Make the resource available for any element that is a child of `MainWindow`:

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <!-- The resource dictionary that contains the shared 'color_UC_BorderBrush' resource -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyLib;component/ResourceDictionaries/myRD.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Window.Resources>

  <MyUserControl />
</Window>
```

**MyUserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="sButton" TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" 
              Value="{DynamicResource color_UC_BorderBrush}" />
    </Style>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <Button Style="{StaticResource sButton}" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Simply using `DynamicResource color_UC_BorderBrush` no errors appear, but the XAML designer doesn't properly load every resource anyway.

Comment: With a test application I can use App.xaml, but anyway the designer doesn't show the controls with theirs properties associated to resources.
It works only at runtime, but what I want is to keep using  `StaticResource`, not using a test application and showing the XAML in designer as it should be at runtime, being in a DLL project.

Comment: You would have to build the application. After that the designer should give you a preview. This works for sure. If you want to stick to StaticResource you must satisfy some requirements. Which you obviously can't. So you are left with DynamicResource - which will also provide you with a  XAML designer preview.

Comment: You should have an application assembly with a MainWindow. When you use the control here you will get a preview.

Comment: Or keep on merging the resource to the user control's ResourceDictionary. This are your  options.

Comment: You wont get a preview directly in the UserControl as it is not part of a logical tree. Therefore, references that point to a resource defined on a parent control, won't resolve. The only way to make it work is to add it to a logical tree e.g. MainWindow. Now the references can resolve at design time. Simply don't deploy this application assembly.